# Converting Pivot from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, pivot

I need to convert a select statement from Oracle to SQL Server. But there is pivot in the script and I couldn't figure it out.

This is the select statement

```
SELECT          user_id,
                cart_id,
                order_total,
                date_abandonment,
                date_abandonment_first,
                fl_abandoned_cart,
                p1_quantity,
                p1_product_name,
                p1_product_description,
                p1_product_type_description,
                p1_product_duration,
                p1_unit_price,
                p2_quantity,
                p2_product_name,
                p2_product_description,
                p2_product_type_description,
                p2_product_duration,
                p2_unit_price,
                p3_quantity,
                p3_product_name,
                p3_product_description,
                p3_product_type_description,
                p3_product_duration,
                p3_unit_price,
                p4_quantity,
                p4_product_name,
                p4_product_description,
                p4_product_type_description,
                p4_product_duration,
                p4_unit_price,
                p5_quantity,
                p5_product_name,
                p5_product_description,
                p5_product_type_description,
                p5_product_duration,
                p5_unit_price
           FROM Cart PIVOT (MAX (quantity) AS quantity,
                                            MAX (product_name) AS product_name,
                                            MAX (product_description) AS product_description,
                                            MAX (product_type_description) AS product_type_description,
                                            MAX (product_duration) AS product_duration,
                                            MAX (unit_price) AS unit_price
                                      FOR (PRODUCT_NUM)
                                      IN  ( (1) AS p1,
                                          (2) AS p2,
                                          (3) AS p3,
                                          (4) AS p4,
                                          (5) AS p5)))
```

When I run this in SQL server it gave me this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

at the line where pivot exists.

Comment: I'm not going to say it will resolve all the issues, but SQL Server doesn't support MAX(Field1) AS something in the pivot declaration. You do the aliasing in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *condition aggregate function* to do pivot.

It can work on SQL-server or Oracle in the same query.

```
SELECT      
    user_id,
    cart_id,
    order_total,
    date_abandonment,
    date_abandonment_first,
    fl_abandoned_cart,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN quantity END)                 p1_quantity
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN product_name END)             p1_product_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN product_description END)      p1_product_description,,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN product_type_description END) p1_product_type_description
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN product_duration END)         p1_product_duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 1 THEN unit_price END)               p1_unit_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN quantity END)                 p2_quantity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN product_name END)             p2_product_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN product_description END)      p2_product_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN product_type_description END) p2_product_type_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN product_duration END)         p2_product_duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 2 THEN unit_price END)               p2_unit_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN quantity END)                 p3_quantity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN product_name END)             p3_product_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN product_description END)      p3_product_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN product_type_description END) p3_product_type_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN product_duration END)         p3_product_duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 3 THEN unit_price END)               p3_unit_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN quantity END)                 p4_quantity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN product_name END)             p4_product_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN product_description END)      p4_product_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN product_type_description END) p4_product_type_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN product_duration END)         p4_product_duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 4 THEN unit_price END)               p4_unit_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN quantity END)                 p5_quantity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN product_name END)             p5_product_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN product_description END)      p5_product_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN product_type_description END) p5_product_type_description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN product_duration END)         p5_product_duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_NUM = 5 THEN unit_price END)               p5_unit_price
FROM Cart 
GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    cart_id,
    order_total,
    date_abandonment,
    date_abandonment_first,
    fl_abandoned_cart
```